# How to fix problem with selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

My code has stopped working, I don't understand why.A month ago, he worked perfectly. The browser opens, but without the desired address in the line and just hangs until the program closes.

```
#import modules/libraries
import os
import sys
import time  #for delay
from selenium import webdriver  #need to install by "pip"
import random

def search():

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ueoio30n.default')

    # open  browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")

    # driver.close()
    os.system("taskkill /im Firefox.exe /f")

def main():
    while 1:
        try:
            print("Started")
            search()
            time.sleep(random.randint(3600, 7200))
        except Exception:
            print('Can\'t start!')
            exit(1)
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date browser version and driver versions? Usually when the browser opens but does nothing that's a signal of a driver mismatch. If everything is current, try reinstalling driver and browser. Have you tried with a different/default profile?

Comment: Thank You, I will check the versions today and respond.

Answer (score 0):

The geckodriver seems to have some serious bug that make the program hang, I ran in same situation without find a solution. Looks like a poor thread handleling is the problem.
I **sugest use of google-chrome or PhantomJS** if you need a headless browser.
You may tray use a diferent geckodriver binary, I assume you checked your current driver supports the version of the firefox you're using.

Comment: Thank You, I will check today the versions and respond.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved after update driver file on my computer. Thank You very much JeffC!